# Effective mass tensor

Tags: mass, electronic-band-theory

I am unsure how the effective mass tensor arises. 
The way I have seen the effective mass derived you take the $\textbf{k}\cdot \textbf{p}$-equation and expand its energies up to second order in perturbation theory. Around band extrema linear terms in $\textbf{k}$ and you get a parabolic expression for the energies from which you can deduce the effective mass. The result of this is an isotropic dispersion relation at the band minimum. How would you get a nonisotropic dispersion starting from the method outlined above?

Answer (score 3):

In 3d, if you expand $E(\vec{k})$ about some $\vec{k}_0$ ($\vec{\delta k} := \vec{k}-\vec{k}_0$), then we get

$$
\begin{split}
E(\vec{k})&=E(\vec{k}_0)+\sum_{i}\delta k_i \frac{\partial E}{\partial k_i} + \frac{1}{2}\sum_{ij}\delta k_i \delta k_j \frac{\partial^2E}{\partial k_i \partial k_j} + \mathcal{O}(\delta k^3) \\
&= E(\vec{k}_0) + \sum_{ij}\frac{\hbar^2}{2m^*_{ij}}\delta k_i \delta k_j  + \mathcal{O}(\delta k^3)
\end{split}
$$

where the effective mass is given by $$\frac{1}{m^{*}_{ij}}= \frac{1}{\hbar^2}\frac{\partial^2E}{\partial k_i \partial k_j} $$ and is generally not isotropic.